# Error when trying to build solution in TFS 2015 sp3 - can't figure it out

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are developing with VS2019, managing all code and builds in On-Prem TFS 2015 service pack 3.

Been running into the following TFS build issue and can't figure out what the real problem is. I verified the FxCopAnalyzers in the solution/projects are installed via Nuget and checked into TFS. This all builds fine locally on my sandbox workstation. The TFS warnings claim the file(s) cannot be found, but they are there. Very frustrating.

In the build config > process tab, the solution is using the Default v12 build template (as are ~50ish other builds) and I've set it to run as a CI build.

I'm missing something, but have been fighting this for so long I think I have tunnel vision. **What could the real problem be?** Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
CSC: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.AnalyzerVersionCheckAnalyzer cannot be created from E:\BuildAgentWorking\4\ACTS\ACTS v1.0 SLN (CI)\src\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.2.9.8\analyzers\dotnet\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
 CSC: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeQuality.CSharp.Analyzers.Maintainability.CSharpVariableNamesShouldNotMatchFieldNamesAnalyzer cannot be created from E:\BuildAgentWorking\4\ACTS\ACTS v1.0 SLN (CI)\src\packages\Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.2.9.8\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeQuality.CSharp.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
 CSC: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.Maintainability.DoNotIgnoreMethodResultsAnalyzer cannot be created from E:\BuildAgentWorking\4\ACTS\ACTS v1.0 SLN (CI)\src\packages\Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.2.9.8\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
 CSC: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.ApiDesignGuidelines.UriPropertiesShouldNotBeStringsAnalyzer cannot be created from E:\BuildAgentWorking\4\ACTS\ACTS v1.0 SLN (CI)\src\packages\Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.2.9.8\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
 CSC: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.ApiDesignGuidelines.AbstractTypesShouldNotHaveConstructorsAnalyzer cannot be created from E:\BuildAgentWorking\4\ACTS\ACTS v1.0 SLN (CI)\src\packages\Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.2.9.8\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've referenced the Microsoft.Net.Compilers pacakge, update it to latest version. If not, add reference to its latest version.

If you have a version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers that is too high for your version of Visual Studio you can get this warning:

```
warning CS8032 ...
```

To find the max version supported see this documentation: Install FxCop analyzers in Visual Studio -> [FxCopAnalyzers package versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/install-fxcop-analyzers?view=vs-2017#fxcopanalyzers-package-versions)

Comment: Okay, installed latest Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset (the one you referenced is flagged as Deprecated and to use Toolset). Now, different error. Please advise.
 ...\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.8.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.props (2): The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

Comment: Have you done nuget restore package?

If you haven’t done it before, please try to execute nuget restore first

If you have done it, please share your pipeline definition and complete log file.

Comment: Note: When building the project, the project will load the required packages from the root directory. Please make sure that your package is in the correct directory.

Comment: Thanks Alina - I was on vacation, so here's the info you asked about...

- Ran Nuget Package restore. VS2019 says "...all packages already installed..."
- FXCopAnalyzers is v2.9.8.
- TFS is v2015 sp3.
- This is a full .Net 4.7.2 console app solution w/n-tier projects.
-  /packages folder is in root of solution, all nuget packages are fully checked into source control.
- Note: All our other solutions use same version of FXCopAnalyzers and build fine, so it has to be a problem with this solution, but I can't figure out what the specific problem is.

Comment: I just saw this on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/migrate-from-fxcop-analyzers-to-net-analyzers?view=vs-2019

Prior to Visual Studio 2019 16.8 and .NET 5.0, these analyzers shipped as Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers NuGet package.

Starting in Visual Studio 2019 16.8 and .NET 5.0, these analyzers are included with the .NET SDK. They are also available as Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers NuGet package. Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers NuGet package will soon be deprecated.

Could this be the issue (VS and .NET updates)?

Comment: Okay, so after uninstalling legacy FxCopAnalyzers, and installing the new NetAnalyzers, and trying to build, I'm getting this error for each project... Please help.

        Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.props (1): The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

Comment: On a hunch, I uninstalled the NetAnalyzers and reinstalled FxCopAnalyzers v3.3.1. Still getting the same error now... "The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format." How can I fix this issue, please?